# How to emulate HTML unordered list behavior?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I am making a to-do checklist webapp and I am using Raphael SVG icons as the checkmarks and status icons next to the list items.

As far as I know, this means that I can't use the standard unordered list bullet-point deal.

Here is what I am using for the list items:

```
<li class='list-item'><span class='item-status'></span> <span class='item'>List Item 2</span></li>
```

I insert the  checkmark icon inside the `item-status` class span with Javascript (Raphael).

and here is my CSS

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
ul li {
    padding-left: 14px;
}
span.item-status {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: -5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
span.item {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

That's fine if the "list item" is less than one line, but if it is more than one line it makes it look like this:
[image]

and I want it to look more like this (mockup):

[image]

**TL;DR:** I want it to look like that second picture, not the first.

Comment: make .item inline-block as well. you can float them also.

Comment: Have you considered using an [icon font](http://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/)?

Comment: I'd appreciate if if someone could let me know why I was down-voted.

@Web_Designer I did consider using a font but that wouldn't make a difference in terms of being able to replace the bullet with it, would it? Plus, Raphael allows for more customization and has a lot of cool built in animation features. And I plan on using multiple icons (not just the checkmark).

Comment: I didn't downvote. I'm just saying that Raphael is a giant 89 kb, and a bit excessive for something as simple as icons.

Comment: @dandavis I'm having the exact same issue even when I make `.item` `inline-block`. I also just tried messing around with float to no avail.

Comment: @Web_Designer Got it, I'll look into other options as well. I'm mostly just making this for personal use though, so I'm not too concerned. The issue my question is about has nothing to do with Raphael though.

Comment: I'm not sure what Raphael is (no link provided). It's use preclude you from using `list-style-position`? (see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-position )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like something along those lines to me:

```
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

ul li {
    padding-left: 14px;

}

span.item  { width: 7em; }

span.item-status, span.item  {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: -5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

</style>

<ul>
  <li class='list-item'><span class='item-status'>*</span> 
       <span class='item'>List Item 2 List Item 2 List Item 2 List Item 2 </span></li>
  <li class='list-item'><span class='item-status'>*</span> 
       <span class='item'>List Item 3 List Item 3 List Item 3 List Item 3 </span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, because it makes the maximum width 7em, but it got me on the right track and it does align the text properly, so thanks, I'll mark it as the correct answer because **setting the width for `.item` was what I needed to do to get it to align properly.** Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is structurally tabular data, a `table` element is the most natural solution. It is also the most robust, since it works even when CSS is disabled:

```
<table>
<caption>List Title</caption>
<tr valign=top><td>✓<td>List Item Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet This is a
pretty long to do people really shouldn’t make
them this long
<tr valign=top><td>✓<td>List Item 2
</table>
```

You can use CSS to make the list title appear in large size and bold

For simplicity, I have used the CHECK MARK character. Replacing it by the use of an icon font trick does not affect the problem presented. (But I would use a simple image rather than such a trick.)